# How to create the new user in the window phone as we createin the pc

Tags: nokia-lumia-535

How to create the new user in the window phone as we create in the pc.By Creating the new user we give the another user limited  access on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone does not work exactly like big Windows. There is only one "user" for a phone and that is setup when you first get the phone, or after resetting the phone.

Comment: There is apps corner that does something similar, offering "you give people access to selected apps on your phone"...